# Run node application with env specifc configuration file

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

I have a node application with environment specific configuration files.
There are multiple environment files, with around 40-50 configuration properties.

Example of configuration files:

```
// config-dev.js
const config = {
 db: {
   host: 'localhost-dev',
   port: 27017,
   name: 'db'
 }
 // More parameters
};


// config-qe.js
const config = {
 db: {
   host: 'localhost-qe',
   port: 27017,
   name: 'db'
 }
 // More parameters
};
```

What I am trying to do is when the node application is run, I want to pass command line env parameter so that application reads the configuration from that specific env file.

```
$ npm run dev

OR

$ npm run qe
```

I am aware of `process.env.PARAM_X`, which are defined in `.env` file, but not sure how it can help in this case.

Is there a way I can pass the `env` while running the node application.
Or some commands that generate/configure the `project.js` file to use specific `env`?

Comment: you can create `.env` for different environment instead of creating config in code and then  use that in code. for reference check [here](https://nodejs.dev/en/learn/how-to-read-environment-variables-from-nodejs/)

Comment: Those don't look like `.env` files at all

Comment: Are you talking about `node myscript.sh value` to pass the environment name as a parameter, or do you really want to use `npm run`?

Comment: @Bergi, I am not sure how this should work, so I asked question. What I want is that, node app should read the `env` specific parameters from a `predefined` file, and that `env` is passed to the app when we run the app. Something like, `$ npm run dev` or `$ npm run qe`.

Comment: @User7723337 Yeah, but `npm run …` is an alias for command defined in the `scripts` section of your *package.json*, and that command could do anything - pass an CLI parameters to your script, run it with some environment variables, it might even read the config file and provide its content as JSON input on stdin…

Comment: Following https://12factor.net/config best practices, you should use environment variables, and your npm commands should run your program using one of several configuration profiles (`qe.env`, `dev.env`, etc). You may use https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv for that.